# Will Search engines hate refreshing a webpage with random content after a specific time period?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

I have hundreds of my own articles in my website. At the moment I am displaying random article topics on my home page. Since the content is random, if a visitor refreshes the page then the page loads with new random content. So I decided to automatically refresh the page after a specific time period.

I got to know that search engines like Google hate automatically refreshing pages.

As my intention is to display random content for visitors, and most of the time page loads with different content, will that cause me to be banned from Google or any other search engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are displaying random content (without redirecting), that will likely not get your site banned with search engines. What it will do however is make it difficult for users to find what search engines indexed.

Each time a search engine like Google indexes your site, they create a "snapshot" of your site and collect content for the [snippet](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en) to display. When search engine users enter keyword terms to search on and find your page(s), the keywords they searched on and snippet displayed for your results will correspond to the content indexed when the Googlebot crawled your site.

If you randomly change that content, then visitors may get confused and bounce (leave) when they see different content there, which [may](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/marketing/bounce-rate/) provide a metric to Google.

It's therefore recommended that the content you want to be indexed and displayed in your snippet continuously, as well as other important content for visitors, not be random. For more on this, see:

[Matt Cutts - How does Google handle pages that have some content that changes each time the page is reloaded?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlwsuL1cbg0&list=PL145F4959C8295A81&index=1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the valuable link.