# Can randomly generated web page content lead to search engine penalties?

Tags: seo, search-engines, penalty, cloaking, random

I have specialized pages with random content. Every time they are accessed or refreshed, different content is displayed.

I have pages that contain randomly selected users of my website:

[image: random users]

I have pages that contain randomly selected images:

[image: random pics]

And I have pages that contain random image albums:

[image: random photo albums]

Can Google and other search engines blacklist my site for this? Is it considered cloaking or any other violation of search engine rules?

For a demonstration of how the content changes every time the page is accessed, see [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Du__Px0FLh8).

Comment: See also: [Could Google penalize randomized, owner-generated content or is it good for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131747/could-google-penalize-randomized-owner-generated-content-or-is-it-good-for-seo) and [Will Search engines hate refreshing a webpage with random content after a specific time period?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51960/will-search-engines-hate-refreshing-a-webpage-with-random-content-after-a-specif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not cloaking (Cloaking is showing different content to Google and Users) and from what you have described what you are doing is not a violation of search engine rules.  (I comment that it is also not random content, its showing selected content - very different).

It is unlikely that Google will penalize you for this, however (and without myunderstanding your language) your site does not appear to me to have much text content or laid out in a way which strikes me as Google friendly.   Similarly - again judging from just the pictures - the pages do not appear to well focussed, ie it is not obvious what the purpose of the site is, or what
topic the page is covering.

I don't think this site will get a great amount of Google love without significant changes to the way content is laid out.